# Pros and Cons of a washer tray

Tags: washing-machine, washer, laundry

We just remodeled our laundry room. It is on the first floor, ceramic tile over concrete. Our washer is a front loader, so does not -fill- with water.

What are the pros and cons of adding a washer tray underneath? Here is my list:

PROS: Catch any minor spills from the washer. Prevent some damage if the washer has a major leak (we don't have a drain to connect the pan to). Others?

CONS: Takes away from the aesthetic of the laundry (its off the hall so guests see it coming into the house). Any particles under it could scratch the tile over time. It takes up space in our small laundry room. Others?

If no tray, what (if anything) should we put under the washer feet to keep them from scratching the tile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you hit the pros and cons of the washer tray pretty well :-) Couple of things I'd consider:

Since the room is tile and concrete, is there a drain in the floor? If so, adding a washer tray is rather unnecessary and I'd leave it out, just ensure that the floor and tile are properly sealed.

(I have seen washer trays that pretty much are the same footprint as the washer, and just raise it off the floor slightly; these blend in very well and would not be as obtrusive as a generic tray, however they may or may not exist for your model of washer, I would start with the manufacturer as they likely have one.)

As for the feet on the washer, most home improvement stores sell small carpet discs to put on furniture legs in order to prevent them from scratching wood floors and such, they also usually have small plastic discs with soft material on them for the same purpose, I'd recommend putting one of those under the washer's feet. Might see if you can find rubber ones, some of the carpet ones are made to glide easily over smooth surfaces, making it easier for chairs and such to be slid around, but you don't want your washer meandering around the laundry room! Although front loaders have a lot less motion/vibration than a top loader so this might not be an issue.

Comment: I would use the rubber pads under the feet. it will dampen the vibrations and keep the machine in place.

Answer (score 1):

For Tile floor rubber feet would be ok.  For vinyl I would use the carpet glider ones or you risk ripping the flooring when/if you ever have to move the washer or dryer.  I had new vinyl put in 4 years ago.  Had the repair guy out for the washer this spring.  Just moved the washer out to clean/paint behind it and the floor was ripped at both back feet :(  I repaired the floor and added stick on glider feet. Made putting it back in place so much easier too.